# div in td with width 100% does not occupy whole td and left 100%, 200% etc does not seem to include border

Tags: html, css

I am trying to modify a webpage where a script positions divs in tds like this

[image: screenshot]

and obviously, the alignment is wrong here.

Those divs are all children of the first table cell, they are absolutely positioned and they are styled by the script to get `left` and `width` to be percentage like `100%`, `200%` etc.

That script is hidden under a obfuscation layer so those percentages are hard parameters as well as the fact that divs are children to the first td on the line.

Can I style the table, table cells or divs to add some funny negative margin (or something else) to fix the alignment?

(I only seek for a css only solution).

```css
table
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td
{
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div
{
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 40px;
  top: 0;
}

#div1
{
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#div2
{
  left: 300%;
  width: 200%;
}

#div3
{
  left: 600%;
  width: 300%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="div1">div 1</div>
      <div id="div2">div 2</div>
      <div id="div3">div 3</div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: replace `border` width `outline` and you will understand your issue. The width:100% doesn't include the border

Answer (score 0):

The problem with height and width made me think about two properties: `box-sizing` and `border`. Both width and height don't include borders in their values, try to inspect your own code snippet and you will see that the size of each `td` is 52x42 and the size of each `div` is 50x40, so borders go on top of main dimensions. To fix it you can play with `box-sizing` property of the table. Another solution will be to replace

```
td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

by

```
td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px #ccc;
}
```

to fix width. Basically `box-shadow` is a nice way to replace borders, don't mess around with `box-sizing` + you can do better animations with it. And to fix height:

```
div {
...
  height: 100% // instead of 40px 
}
```